# Open Iframe with Document mode independent of Parent Window

Tags: html, iframe

I have a web page in IE8 Compatibility mode.
Need to open a Iframe inside a ExtJS window with IE 11 mode because i need to use HTML 5 file controls.

Parent page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=IE8" />
---
```

Iframe page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE" />
--
```

With no luck..Is there any possible fix for this.